# Uploading file to parse using cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, parse-platform

I have been trying to upload a jpg to my Parse.com app using cURL in PHP for the server. The file gets created appropriately but doesn't consist of proper data ...In short the image is corrupted
here's my code

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$ParseAppID = "X-Parse-Application-Id: ..." ;
$ParseRestKey = "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ..." ;
$imageContent = "Content-Type: image/jpeg";
$mimetypeImage = 'image/jpeg';
$POST = "POST";

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){


    if (isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['image'])) {
        $text = $_POST['text'];
        $image = $_POST['image'];

        $binary = base64_decode($image);
        $filename = "file.jpg";
        $file2 = "/public_html/VolleyTest/file.jpg";
        file_put_contents($filename, $binary);
        $postname = 'name';

        $cfile = new CURLFile($file2,$mimetypeImage,$postname);
        $data = array($cfile);

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $POST);
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($ParseAppID, $ParseRestKey, $imageContent));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.parse.com/1/files/$filename");

        $result = curl_exec( $curl );

        curl_close( $curl );

        $result = json_decode($result);
        echo  $result->name;
        echo $result->url;
        echo json_encode($result);


    }
//Response -> Error
    else{

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Improper request";
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}
//Response -> Error

else{

    $response["success"] = -1;
    $response["message"] = "Improper request no POST request found";
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

}
?>
```

I tried a lot but every time I get an empty image ... Please Help

Comment: Could you please link the documentation that makes you think that this should work? I can only find the SDK docs here: https://parse.com/docs/php/guide#files and wonder why you are not using it this way?

Comment: according to parse the cURL command must have file in @ format but its deprecated now in PHP ... instead we have to use cURLFile

Comment: Hence I used this http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php but its not working

Comment: When you say "according to parse" ... where can I see the docs for this? Sorry for asking this stupidly, but I don't have any experience with parse.com and would like to see where it says that you can do it with curl like that. Furthermore: You did not really say why you do not just use the SDK - care to elaborate? :)

Comment: Ohh.. that one .... I got the info at https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#files ... I am just trying to use it with PHP

Comment: Thanks for the link, max. I am just guessing here, but, could you try giving your $data array a named key for the $cfile, like so: `$data = array('myfile' => $cfile);` Not quite sure if that does the trick, but I just find it a tiny bit odd to have a postfiled that has no name (or the name "0"). If that does not help, what return code (HTTP code) and/or response content does their API give you?